# Unanswered DevOps questions

Tags: discussion

currently this site has [58 unanswered questions](https://superuser.com/search?q=devops%20answers%3A0) mentioning DevOps.

Is there any sense to move them to DevOps SE to increase the chance for an answer?

Comment: Perhaps it is possible for administrators to leave a comment to encourage people to migrate the questions to DevOps?

Answer (score 5):

There are maybe a handful of questions that are younger than 60 days old.

[We cannot migrate questions older than 60 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136537/is-too-old-to-migrate-a-good-reason-not-to-migrate) and I do not see any real benefit in shoving a heap of old questions, that OP could well have abandoned, given up on, or solved by other means, at another site.  At best it could just be added churn, at worst it is a lot of extra work for the target site to deal with.

If Devops **want** the questions and they are explicitly off topic here then that would be a different problem, one that only SE developers would be able to solve. (60 day limit as above)